# Double reference delegate

Tags: c#

Sorry, I did not describe the real problem. And I decided to edit my question.
How can I simplify my example to dispense with the `GetDelegate` statistical function?
There are many classes of `C` in which, for a specific event `E`, it is required to perform the action `Cd`. But before performing the very action of `Cd`, you need to check the permission. The results of the permission check, I get in the main stream of class `A`, the method call back. And already by the result of the check I decide whether to start the action `Cd`.
That is, in class `C` for event `E`, it is necessary to set the `Cd` for the delegate declared in class `A`. And from class `A` to call `Cd` if permission is obtained.
In a real application, there is multithreading.

```
    public delegate void D();
public delegate ref D GetD();
class A//This is Thread 1
{
    static D d;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c1 = new C(GetDelegate, "NAME1");
        C c2 = new C(GetDelegate, "NAME2");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static ref D GetDelegate()
    {
        return ref d;
    }
    void OnPermissionsResult(bool result)//This is a permission check callback method.
    {
        if (result)
        {
            d();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You do not have permission.\r");
        }
    }
}
class C//This is Thread 2
{
    string name;
    GetD getd;
    public C(GetD getd, string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.getd = getd;           
    }
    void M()
    {
        //This is example of event 'E'
        button.Click += () =>
        {
            getd() = () =>//This is Ation 'Cd'
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Action: {name}\r");
            };
            CheckPermissions();//Begin check permission.               
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be an XY problem. What is the underlying problem you’re trying to solve with this? Maybe there’s another way to do is properly.

Comment: You can get rid of delegate1, just replace it by Action, but you cannot, AFAIK, get rid of GetDelegate1 because of the ref modifier on the return type.

Comment: I agree with Sami; this is a strange thing to do in the first place. Presumably you're doing this because you have some problem to solve, but what that problem is, that's not clear.  Normally you would not pass around the address of a variable if you wanted to mutate a property of a class; normally that class would implement an interface with a property, and you'd pass around a reference to the interface. The fact that you're doing this with a *static* property is even more suspicious that something fundamentally strange is going on here.

Comment: Are there different permission checks for different actions, or are they all the same? If they can be different then you have a bigger problem in a multithreaded program, because you can end up with the permission check for one action governing the execution of a different one, which is obviously a security hole.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, this is a strange thing to do, and it therefore sounds like you are asking an "XY question".  An XY question is "I have come up with a strange solution to a problem, that strange solution does not work quite right, and now I'm going to ask a question that does not make much sense because it is about my strange solution, and not about my real problem".  Ask a question about the real problem!

That said, normally what we'd do if we wanted to represent "I can read and write a property of another class", is not use a ref-returning delegate, but rather an interface with a property.  I would have written your code -- assuming I would have written it to solve your real problem at all -- like this:

```
public delegate void D();
internal interface I 
{
  D D { get; set; }
}
class P : I
{
  public D D { get; set; }
  static void Main()
  {
    (new P()).M();
  }
  private void M()
  {
    C c1 = new C(this, "NAME1");
    C c2 = new C(this, "NAME2");
    c1.SetD();
    this.D();
    c2.SetD();
    this.D();
  }
}
class C
{
  private I i;
  private string name;
  public C(I i, string name) 
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.i = i;
  }
  public void SetD()
  {
    this.i.D = () => { whatever };
  }
}
```

No messing around with static fields or ref returning delegates required.

Comment: As in class `C`, directly assign the delegate value d via the reference, without resorting to the `GetDelegate` function.